# Range through values within variable containing dashes in Golang templates

Tags: go, go-templates

I would like to range through values specified under a variable containing dashes within Golang template:

```
data:
  init: |
{{- range .Values.something.something-else.values.list }}
{{ . | indent 4 }}{{ end }}
```

I've seen that to access values from a variable with dashes in the name `index` function should be used.

I'm not understanding though how to combine the two functions.

Comment: That looks suspiciously like YAML, if it is then there might be a better way than `text/template`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `index` function is documented at [`text/template`: Functions section](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/):

```
index
    Returns the result of indexing its first argument by the
    following arguments. Thus "index x 1 2 3" is, in Go syntax,
    x[1][2][3]. Each indexed item must be a map, slice, or array.
```

To use `index`: pass the value you want to index, and the values to index by, e.g.

```
index . "Values" "something" "something-else" "values" "list"
```

Combined with the `{{range}}` action:

```
Items:
{{range index . "Values" "something" "something-else" "values" "list"}}
    {{.}},
{{end}}
```

See a simplified working example:

```
func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(src))
    m := map[string]interface{}{
        "something": map[string]interface{}{
            "something-else": map[string]interface{}{
                "list": []string{"one", "two", "three"},
            },
        },
    }
    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, m); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

const src = `data:
{{- range index . "something" "something-else" "list" }} {{.}},{{ end }}`
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mNLQ07dWn8A)):

```
data: one, two, three,
```